# How to delete the more than one duplicate row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id   number
1       20
2       20
3       30
4       18
```

Hello guys, I have a table called `numbers`,this table contains thousands of rows--sample above--The table has so many duplicates. I want a way to simply delete those duplicates using mysql query. The query should also delete the original number and the duplicate itself. For instance the `id` with `1` and `2` value should be deleted since they are duplicate.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with a `join`:

```
delete n
    from numbers n join
         (select number
          from numbers
          group by number
          having count(*) > 1
         ) nn
         on n.number = nn.number;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb786) is an example on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

We can get duplicates with group by and having clause

```
Delete a.* from TableA a
Where Number in ( 
Select number from (
select number from tableA 
group by number
having count(*) > 1)
)
```

Comment: This generates an error in MySQL.  I can understand how you would answer this way; I fail to understand the upvote.

Comment: @Gordon, I will verify , I see that group by and having are available in MySQL , probably missed some thing

Comment: @Gordon, updated it instead of number , I was using id

Comment: . . MySQL doesn't allow you to have a subquery that references the table being modified in an `update` or `delete` statement.  I'll let you figure out how to fix it.